# nth-child not working as expected

Tags: css

I have a problem with using `nth-child(n)`. Lets say i have such list:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

And styles:

```
li {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

For some reason, such combination sets `margin: 0` for every fourth `li` element. What i'm trying to achieve is to set this zero margin for every sixth `li`. Can you please advise me how my css should look like?

Comment: You must have some stray elements inbetween your `li` because it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/f25eE/

Answer (score 5):

`6n+6` means start at 6 then do every other 6 from that point on so just using `6n` is equivalent in this situation:

```
li:nth-child(6n) {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, this resource can be useful: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

If this doesn't work for you, your selector is wrong. Use something more specific like `body > ul > li:nth-child(6n)` or `body > ul > li:nth-of-type(6n)` which will only select every 6th li element.

Answer (score 1):

It actually targets only the sixth as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/6F37a/ (*although the `+6` is redundant*)

Perhaps another rule is messing the margins..

Comment: well it's a bit strange cause when i'll use "Inspect" for the fourth `li`, i can see in object inspector that this `nth-child(6n)` is applied to this element

Comment: @mbajur, are you sure there are only `li` elements under the `ul` and that your html validates ?